# How to read SMS with C++ Builder in Android

Tags: android, delphi, c++builder-2010

This time I try to read sms using C++ Builder environment and what I found in internet is one example written in Delphi. I do not need all information from this example so I crack this code to one parametr. So the example looks like this and is taken from this post.
[How to code read sms messages from android kitkat Delphi XE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520148/how-to-code-read-sms-messages-from-android-kitkat-delphi-xe8)

```
function TForm1.Process_SMS: string;
var
  cursor: JCursor;
  uri: Jnet_Uri;
  address, person, msgdatesent, protocol, msgread, msgstatus, msgtype,
  msgreplypathpresent, subject, body,
  smsid, servicecenter, locked: string;
  msgunixtimestampms: int64;
  id_smsid, addressidx, personidx, msgdateidx, msgdatesentidx, protocolidx,
  msgreadidx, msgstatusidx, msgtypeidx, msgreplypathpresentidx, subjectidx,
  bodyidx, servicecenteridx, lockedidx: integer;
begin
  uri := StrToJURI('content://sms/inbox');
  cursor := SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query(uri, nil, nil, nil, nil);
  id_smsid := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('_id'));
  addressidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('address'));
  personidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('person'));
  msgdateidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('date'));
  msgdatesentidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('date_sent'));
  protocolidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('protocol'));
  msgreadidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('read'));
  msgstatusidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('status'));
  msgtypeidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('type'));
  msgreplypathpresentidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('reply_path_present'));
  subjectidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('subject'));
  bodyidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('body'));
  servicecenteridx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('service_center'));
  lockedidx := cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('locked'));

  while (cursor.moveToNext) do
  begin
    smsid := JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smsid));
    address := JStringToString(cursor.getString(addressidx));
    person := JStringToString(cursor.getString(personidx));
    msgunixtimestampms := cursor.getLong(msgdateidx);
    msgdatesent := JStringToString(cursor.getString(msgdatesentidx));
    protocol := JStringToString(cursor.getString(protocolidx));
    msgread := JStringToString(cursor.getString(msgreadidx));
    msgstatus := JStringToString(cursor.getString(msgstatusidx));
    msgtype := JStringToString(cursor.getString(msgtypeidx));
    msgreplypathpresent := JStringToString(cursor.getString(msgreplypathpresentidx));
    subject := JStringToString(cursor.getString(subjectidx));
    body := JStringToString(cursor.getString(bodyidx));
    servicecenter := JStringToString(cursor.getString(servicecenteridx));
    locked := JStringToString(cursor.getString(lockedidx));
    Listbox1.Items.Add(subject);
    // I plan on deleting messages here
    //SharedActivity.getContentResolver.delete(uri, StringToJString('_ID=' + smsid), nil);
    Result := IntToStr(trunc(msgunixtimestampms/1000)) + ' ' + address + ' ' + body;
  end;
end;
```

In my example I want to read only body of the sms message and looks like this:

```
_di_JCursor cursor;
  _di_Jnet_Uri uri;

   uri = StrToJURI( "content://sms/inbox" );
   cursor = SharedActivity()->getContentResolver()->query( uri, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr );

   int bodyidx = cursor->getColumnIndex( StringToJString("body") );
   String body;

   while ( cursor->moveToNext )
   {
    body = JStringToString( cursor->getString(bodyidx) );
   }

   Memo1->Lines->Add(body);
```

I have some old and one new sms and after click button to read sms I got errors which I do not understand:

> First chance exception at $61C3F582. Exception class Bus error (10).
>   Process Project1.apk (4600) First chance exception at $61D2B76E.
>   Exception class Segmentation fault (11). Process Project1.apk (4731)

I ask about suggestion about what is wrong with code or something else